# Can data.table's fread() skip second empty row and keep first row headers?

Tags: r, csv, data.table, fread

I am trying to read a CSV where column headers are on row 1, but then row 2 is empty and data starts in row 3. I tried the various options below, but always end up with generic `V#` column names. Any ideas on how to retain column headers?

```r
fread("https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/green_tripdata_2013-08.csv",
      header = F)
fread("https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/green_tripdata_2013-08.csv",
      skip = 0)
fread("https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/green_tripdata_2013-08.csv",
      skip = 1)
fread("https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/green_tripdata_2013-08.csv",
      blank.lines.skip = T)
fread("https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/green_tripdata_2013-08.csv",
      skip = 0, blank.lines.skip = T)
fread("https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/green_tripdata_2013-08.csv",
      header = F, skip = 0, blank.lines.skip = T)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
url ="https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/green_tripdata_2013-08.csv"
df = fread(url,header=F)
headers = names(fread(url, nrows=0))
setnames(df, old=1:length(headers), new = headers)
```

I notice that there are 20 headers, but 22 columns returned. Therefore, I named the first 20 columns with the 20 names in headers.

As suggested by r2evans in comments, to avoid the double download/read, you could do something like this:

```
url ="https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/green_tripdata_2013-08.csv"

# download file
tfile = tempfile()
curl::curl_download(url,destfile = tfile)

# read to get headers
headers = names(fread(tfile, nrows=0))

# read to get data
df = fread(tfile, header=F)

# set the names based on `headers`
setnames(df, old=1:length(headers), new = headers)

# remove the file
file.remove(tfile)
```

Comment: I like the `nrows=0` trick.

Comment: For "niceness", it might be preferable to download the file *once* and read it (then delete it); with larger and/or many files, this doubles the bandwidth/download requirements. (If you can, see my [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71053836/3358272) for this portion.)

Comment: thanks @r2evans.. that is very helpful suggestion

Comment: Thank you @langtang and r2evans, looks great and solves my issue.